# mutual authentication using certificate

Tags: java, google-chrome, authentication, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I have been developing a web application using java and I wanted to use implement mutual certificate authentication.

I used a self-signed certificate, I put it on my browser(chrome) and to my **glassfish trust store(cacerts.jks)** and configure my web.xml and sun-web.xml and works fine.

When I run the application it asked me to choose a certificate and after the proper authentication the page I requested is displayed.

However I need to make different certificate(actually three) and based on the role I want to authorize the user.

But even if I created other two certificates and added to the browser certificate list, the browser didn't list them on the certificate selection prompt except for the first certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I am adding the certificate to the wrong version of **glassfish trust store(cacerts.jks)** now everything is working fine. The browser lists all certificate I added and authorize correctly according to the role.